# How to create a command that kills a certain team only with a snowball

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /kill @a[score_Hider_min=1,r=3]
```

The above is the command I'm using.
This is running on a loop and I'm  trying to use it to kill people that have that score. Is there a way to do this just based on what team they are on?

Comment: There's a variable for which team someone's on, right?

Answer (score 3):

The `team` parameter allows you to target based on the scoreboard team:

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /kill @a[score_Hider_min=1,r=3,team=TeamName]
```

Alternatively, you can target players that are **not** on that team (including those not on *any* team):

```
/say @a[team=!TeamName]
```

By leaving the value blank, you can target players **not** on any team.

```
/say @a[team=]
```

And by using the NOT operator with a blank value, you can target players on *any* team.

```
/say @a[team=!]
```

The wiki has a list of target selector parameters [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).